# Index of solveMazeUtil is out of range

Tags: python, backtracking

I am learning about backtracking method to solve Rat in Maze problem
Here is my code:

```
def Rat():
    # Python3 program to solve Rat in a Maze
    # problem using backracking

    # The maze can be in any shape where 1 is the path and 0 is the wall
    N = int(input("Which size of maze by dimension do you want"))
    maze = [[int(randint(0, 1)) for i in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
    print(maze)
    print(len(maze))
    if maze [0][0] == 0:
        maze [0][0] = 1
    # A utility function to print solution matrix sol
    # A utility function to check if x, y is valid
    def isSafe( maze, x, y ):
        if x >= 0 and x < N and y >= 0 and y < N and maze[x][y] == 1:
            print(x)
            print(y)
            return True
        return False
    def solveMaze( maze ):
        global solveMazeUtil
        # Creating a 4 * 4 2-D list
        sol = [ [ 0 for j in range(N) ] for i in range(N) ]
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, 0, 0, sol) == False:
            print("Solution doesn't exist");
            return False
        elif solveMazeUtil(maze, 0, 0, sol) == False:
            return sol
        # A recursive utility function to solve Maze problem
        def solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y, sol):
            if x == N - 1 and y == N - 1 and maze[x][y]== 1:
                sol[x][y] = 1
                return True
            # Check if maze[x][y] is valid
            if isSafe(maze, x, y) == True:
                # Check if the current block is already part of solution path.
                if sol[x][y] == 1:
                    return False
                # mark x, y as part of solution path
                sol[x][y] = 1
                # Move forward in x direction
                if solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == True:
                    return True
                # If moving in x direction doesn't give solution
                # then Move down in y direction
                if solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y + 1, sol) == True:
                    return True
                # If moving in y direction doesn't give solution then
                # Move back in x direction
                if solveMazeUtil(maze, x - 1, y, sol) == True:
                    return True
                # If moving in backwards in x direction doesn't give solution
                # then Move upwards in y direction
                if solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y - 1, sol) == True:
                    return True
                # If none of the above movements work then
                # BACKTRACK: unmark x, y as part of solution path
                sol[x][y] = 0
                return False
    output = solveMaze(maze)
    one_row = [x for l in maze for x in l]
    one_row_2nd = [x for l in maze for x in l]
    for i in range(len(one_row)):
        if one_row[i] != one_row_2nd[i] and one_row_2nd[i] == 0:
            one_row_2nd[i] = one_row[i]
        else:
            continue
    fin_sol = np.reshape(one_row_2nd, (N, N))
    #print(sol_1)
    arr = np.array(fin_sol)
    #print out raw and solution
    if sol != False:
        plt.figure()
        f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize= (10,10)) 
        axarr[0].imshow(maze)
        axarr[1].imshow(arr)
    else:
        plt.figure()
        f, axarr = plt.subplots(figsize= (5,5)) 
        axarr.imshow(maze)
# This code is taken idea and modified from the code of Shiv Shankar
Rat()
```

And this is the original one:

```
# Python3 program to solve Rat in a Maze
# problem using backracking

# Maze size
N = 4

# A utility function to print solution matrix sol
def printSolution( sol ):
    
    for i in sol:
        for j in i:
            print(str(j) + " ", end ="")
        print("")

# A utility function to check if x, y is valid
# index for N * N Maze
def isSafe( maze, x, y ):
    
    if x >= 0 and x < N and y >= 0 and y < N and maze[x][y] == 1:
        return True
    
    return False

""" This function solves the Maze problem using Backtracking.
    It mainly uses solveMazeUtil() to solve the problem. It
    returns false if no path is possible, otherwise return
    true and prints the path in the form of 1s. Please note
    that there may be more than one solutions, this function
    prints one of the feasable solutions. """
def solveMaze( maze ):
    
    # Creating a 4 * 4 2-D list
    sol = [ [ 0 for j in range(4) ] for i in range(4) ]
    
    if solveMazeUtil(maze, 0, 0, sol) == False:
        print("Solution doesn't exist");
        return False
    
    printSolution(sol)
    return True
    
# A recursive utility function to solve Maze problem
def solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y, sol):
    
    # if (x, y is goal) return True
    if x == N - 1 and y == N - 1 and maze[x][y]== 1:
        sol[x][y] = 1
        return True
        
    # Check if maze[x][y] is valid
    if isSafe(maze, x, y) == True:
        # Check if the current block is already part of solution path.
        if sol[x][y] == 1:
            return False
        
        # mark x, y as part of solution path
        sol[x][y] = 1
        
        # Move forward in x direction
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == True:
            return True
            
        # If moving in x direction doesn't give solution
        # then Move down in y direction
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y + 1, sol) == True:
            return True
        
        # If moving in y direction doesn't give solution then
        # Move back in x direction
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x - 1, y, sol) == True:
            return True
            
        # If moving in backwards in x direction doesn't give solution
        # then Move upwards in y direction
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y - 1, sol) == True:
            return True
        
        # If none of the above movements work then
        # BACKTRACK: unmark x, y as part of solution path
        sol[x][y] = 0
        return False

# Driver program to test above function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialising the maze
    maze = [ [1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1] ]
            
    solveMaze(maze)

# This code is contributed by Shiv Shankar
```

At first, it warned that:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'solveMazeUtil' referenced before assignment
So I did put solveMazeUtil in global type, but it then noticed:
List index out of range (This only happens if there is a solution, if not, it can run smoothly)
Can someone help me

Comment: You define `solveMazeUtil` inside `solveMaze`. So it should not be declared as a global. Instead simply move the lines that call `solveMazeUtil` below the function definition

Comment: Alternatively reduce the indentation of the definition of `solveMazeUtil` so that it isn't defined inside `solveMaze`

Comment: thanks,I did as you said and it was solved, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make `solveMazeUtil` as a global function. Move the  `solveMazeUtil` function outside `solveMaze` and that should work.
Currently, your function `solveMaze` is calling `solveMazeUtil` before its definition and it's unable to locate that file.